How can I get an elemment containing text wich has other things inside with XPath?
<button data-bn-type="button" type="button" class=" css-m5s6fw">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" class="css-164cs52">
            <path d="M13.5 3h-3v7.5H3v3h7.5V21h3v-7.5H21v-3h-7.5V3z" fill="currentColor">
            </path>   
        </svg>  
    Add 
</button>

I want to retreive the button with the text 'Add', but as you can see it haves some more tags inside it (the svg with a path inside) along with the text, so XPath "//button[contains(text(), 'Add')]" won't work.
I don't know exactly how XPath works and even less how contains() work.
XPath "//button[contains(text(), 'Add')]" won't work.
Error: TimeoutError: Waiting for selector .//button[contains(text(), "Add")] failed: Waiting failed: 30000ms exceeded

It's best to show a [mcve] of your Puppeteer code and the site you're working with. Many sites are dynamic and various factors like iframes, shadow DOMs, bot detection, arbitrary JS timing behavior and visibility can prevent elements from being selectable. XPath is usually not necessary, and in my opinion, an antipattern in Puppeteer. There are better ways to select by text, like p-selectors.

@ggorlen: Although I do not live the the Puppeteer space, I suspect that calling XPath "an antipattern in Puppeteer"  isn't entirely fair -- it is, after all, a powerful and standard means of selecting markup well beyond the Puppeteer realm.  Nonetheless, I upvoted a couple of your related answers that were very helpful.

@kjhughes That's nice of you. XPath is certainly powerful, but it's generally overkill for most web selection, which has simpler and more natural CSS selectors that are perfectly designed for selecting HTML elements. In Playwright (Microsoft's version of Puppeteer), the docs caution against XPath. That said, even CSS selectors are discouraged--the modern approach is a direct aria role or text selector, followed by test ids. In Puppeteer, XPath has generally been used for text selection (my linked post covers this pretty thoroughly).

@kjhughes Another consideration is that in Puppeteer, you have to add a prefix like ::-p-xpath() just to enable its use, on top of the XPath itself (unfortunately OP hasn't shown their whole waitForSelector() call here). See this post for details and a comparison against a CSS selector.
